# Removing video streaming audio device from my Mac

Tags: macos, audio, video

Recently I installed ScreenFlow app and then I found this thing called "video streaming audio device " in my audio selection and it screws everything up. Sometimes I can't hear people and sometimes they can't hear me. I am trying to get rid of it but nothing has worked.

So far I have tired:

1. removing the ScreenFlow app.
2. removing "video streaming audio device " from Audio MIDI Setup app but (but the <kbd>-</kbd> sign is disabled.

Any help?

[image]